# Adding Google analytics with consent manager to a SvelteKit website

Tags: typescript, google-analytics, svelte, sveltekit

I need to add Google Analytics to a SvelteKit website. The instructions from Google is that the script below should be added to the `<head>` tag, so I thought that I could just add it in `app.html`. The problem is that I need to use Consent Mode to follow GDPR regulations. To do that, I need to be able to read and write to some kind of variable to enable and disable analytics.

As far as I can tell, I can't access any variables from within the `<head>` tag. I also tried adding the same code to a `<svelte:head>` tag in `__layout.svelte`, but it seems like I can't access variables there either.

I plan on tracking the cookie consent using a store, and persisting that value to local storage, but I am open to other solutions as well.

Here is the code that should be added to the `<head>` tag:

```js
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-H5XGB0JC8S"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-H5XGB0JC8S');
</script>
```

Here is the code that has to be added to disable analytics:

```js
gtag('consent', 'default', {
  analytics_storage: 'denied',
  ad_storage: 'denied'
});
```

And here is the code to call to update a value:

```js
gtag('consent', 'update', {
  'ad_storage': 'granted'
});
```

I assume that the last code snippet should be called when the accept button is pressed, but if I call `gtag` from anywhere else other than the same place as the first code snippet, I get a warning saying that the function is not defined.

Should I add the code somewhere else, or should it be done in some other way?

Maybe I should mention that I am using TypeScript as well.